# Does this implementation of CountDownTimer correctly handle any possible memory leaks?

Tags: java, android

Hi I am creating a countdown timer in my application and I am afraid it may cause a memory leak as I am reusing the same object from my activity to resume the countdown timer by creating a new instance of a new countdown timer with the time that the previous timer had left when the user stopped it.

This is my CountDownTimer implementation:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;
    private long timeRemaining = 20000;
    private TextView mTextField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mTextField = findViewById(R.id.textViewTimer);

        createTimer(timeRemaining);

        Button pauseButton = findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (myCountDownTimer != null) {
                    myCountDownTimer.cancel();
                }
            }
        });

        Button resumeButton = findViewById(R.id.resumeButton);
        resumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createTimer(timeRemaining);
            }
        });
    }

    public void createTimer(long millisInFuture) {


        myCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                timeRemaining = millisUntilFinished;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        };

        myCountDownTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (myCountDownTimer != null) {
            myCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (myCountDownTimer != null) {
            myCountDownTimer.cancel();
            myCountDownTimer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this implementation looking good so that the garbage collector will manage the countdowntimer correctly?

Comment: What makes you think you're going to leak? You create a new object, initialized with the time from the previous object. You do not, however, retain a reference to that old instance, so why do you think it's not going to be garbage collected? Anyhow, in the future, direct requests for code review to https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, what I was afraid is that what could happen if a countdowntimer has finished or I have canceled it and I cancel it again. Is it important to cancel the countdowntimer if only if I know that it is running or it doesn't matter if I cancel it although it is already canceled?